# AttributeError - 'list' object has no attribute 'lower' with Countvectorizer

Tags: machine-learning, twitter, classification, text-classification, countvectorizer

I'm trying to vectorize some tweets so I can put it in a list and use it in a classficator.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
 trained_model = pickle.load(open(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + "/MLP_classificado.pkl", 'rb'))
   
    for tweet in public_tweets:
        tweets.append(tweet.text)
    
   vec_tweets = vectorizer.fit(tweets)
   
   #Model predict
   classification = trained_model.predict(vectorizer.transform([[vec_tweets]]))
```

Does anyone have any ideia how to solve this? Do I need to retrieve tweets in some other way to make it work?